# How to auto-populate the city and state input fields once user enters the valid United States zip code value into an input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zipcode

Actually, I had this working functionality in my website. But suddenly the URL from which I'm getting the state and city in form of AJAX response has stopped working.

Now the biggest issue I'm facing is how to make this thing workable again?

Following is my current code :

**HTML Code :**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="20"  id="store_zipcode" name="store_zipcode" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" readonly="readonly" name="store_city" id="store_city" value="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" name="store_state" id="store_state" value="" size="20">
```

**jQuery-AJAX Code :**

```
//Function called in Store Add/Edit form when user enters valid US Zip Code value  
    function GetLocation() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();      

        var store_zipcode = $("#store_zipcode").val();

        var complete_address = store_zipcode;

        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': complete_address }, function (results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            $("#store_longitude").val(longitude);
            $("#store_latitude").val(latitude);
          } else {
              //alert("Request failed.")
            }
        });

        var el = $(this);

        if (el.val().length === 5) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: "zip=" + el.val(),
            success: function(result, success) {
              $("#store_city").val(result.city);
              $("#store_state").val(result.state);
            }
          });
        }  
      }
      //Call to the function to display location details on Store add/edit form
      $( "#store_zipcode" ).focusout(GetLocation);
```

One more thing is I can't store the city and state names into my database. I'll have to take from some data source only like I did above. But the data source should be reliable. The functionality should never get collapse.

If you want more information about the issue I'm talking about you can check the question just I asked at following URL: [Link to the question previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737720/how-to-resolve-this-issue-warning-as-cross-origin-request-blocked-coming-in).

Comment: That web address does not resolve

Comment: Wouldn't this be as simple as changing the URL you were pulling the data originally from and perhaps needing to look at how to get your city and state from the new service you are calling?

Comment: The URL in the question does not resolve, so I have edited it out (it's still in the code sample and edit history in the unlikely event that anyone wishes to see it). The solution is to use a working service, but other than that, the fault in this question cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that the elevenbasetwo.com domain is not currently online. The zip.elevenbasetwo.com subdomain does not have a valid DNS entry and so will not produce any result at the moment. This is probably just a temporary thing - try it again in a few hours.